# Delete Nested document in Elastic search using NEST C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

How do we delete only nested objects and not the index in elastic search using Nest library.

```
public class Make
{
   public string MakeId {get;set;}
   public string MakeName {get;set;}
   public string Address { get;set;}

   [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Nested)]
   public List<Cars> Models {get;set;}
}
```

In the above mapping i want to delete one entry of Models without deleting whole index.

I tried deleting using DeleteByQuery but it deletes the entire Make index.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind scripts, you can try:

```
var updateResponse = client.Update<Make>(descriptor => descriptor
    .Id(documentId)
    .Script("ctx._source.models.remove(0)")
    .Lang("groovy"));
```

or without script

```
var make = new Make {Id = "1", Models = new List<Cars>
{
    new Cars{Name = "test"},
    new Cars{Name = "test2"}
}};

make.Models.RemoveAt(1);

var updateResponse = client.Update<Make>(descriptor => descriptor
    .Id("1")
    .Doc(make));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob. That means delete is always meant for entire document and in no way we can delete only nested object. So we need to do only update for nested document.